# Construct a shape in the form of a ring on C#

Tags: c#, .net, shapes

I need method for construct ring (сircle from which cut a circle of smaller radius) and return it as `System.Windows.Shapes.Shape`. Can I do this with `Path`? May be exist another ways?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you use an ellipse with a very thick stroke, but a transparent fill? Admittedly that doesn't work if you want the edges of the ring itself to be a different colour to the filled part...

Alternatively, I'd start looking at a `Path` containing two `EllipseGeometry` elements in a `GeometryGroup` with a `FillRule` of `EvenOdd` or a `CombineGeometry` with a `GeometryCombineMode` of `Exclude`. For example:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#CCCCFF">
  <Path.Data>
    <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
      <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="100" RadiusY="100" Center="125,125" />
      </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
      <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Center="125,125" />
      </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
    </CombinedGeometry>
  </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Produces this:

[image]

Am I right in saying that's what you were after?